# Websocket client disconnects automatically after some time

Tags: laravel-4, websocket, notifications

I am using websockets in my laravel project. I have opened a port by PHP that is 8000 and it is working fine. I am connecting to the port by following in in view file:

```
function WebSocketInit()
         {
            if ("WebSocket" in window)
            {
               // Let us open a web socket
               ws = new ReconnectingWebSocket("ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000");
            }
            else
            {
               // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
               alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
            }
         }
        WebSocketInit();
        ws.onopen = function(){
            console.log( "Connected." );
        };
        ws.onclose = function(){
            ws.refresh();
            console.log( "Disconnected." );
        };
```

It connects well first time but if I refresh my page then it disconnects and do not re-connect most of the time. Sometimes, it connects but takes few seconds. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `ReconnectingWebSocket()`?  That's not a standard browser feature so we need to know what library it is and what characteristics/features it has.

Comment: We have used ReconnectingWebSocket() from https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket.